# Is the memory allocated using malloc inside kernel accessible by threads of other blocks?

Tags: cuda

If one thread allocates a global memory using malloc call inside kernel, is that memory accessible by threads of other blocks also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this memory comes from the so-called "device heap" and it is accessible by any device code (any thread) from any kernel running on that GPU.

Note that this applies even to kernels other than the one that actually did the `malloc` operation.

The above statement applies until application termination, or until you explicitly free that memory using an in-kernel `free()` call on the pointer.

You may wish to read [the documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations) on the in-kernel `malloc()` functionality.  There are size limits which you can modify, and its good practice if you are having trouble with such a code, to check the return pointer for NULL after that `malloc()` call.  If it is NULL, that is the API method to signal an error (usually meaning you ran out of allocation space on the "device heap").

A pointer allocated in this fashion **cannot** participate in (be used in) any host API for data movement, such as `cudaMemcpy`.  It is usable/accessible from device code only.

Also note that the `malloc()` operation, like most device code you write, is performed *per-thread*.  Each thread that executes the `malloc()` call will do so independently, and each thread (assuming no failures) will receive a separate pointer, to a separate allocation.  However all such pointers are usable subsequently by any code running on that device, until they are explictly freed.